# How to uninstall DEVONThink?

Tags: macos, terminal

I had installed DEVONthink software Pro Office 2.7 for trying it, but now it refuses to be uninstalled from my computer. It says there is a puglin in use when I simply try to trash the application. I've already trashed all folders and database related to it, yet the application can't be uninstalled by the conventional method.

Then, I tried to uninstall the app via Terminal without success; it still there. Any thought about how could I get rid of this?

```
mdfind -name "DEVONthink"
sudo rm -rif /Applications/DEVONthink Pro.app
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue:

```
sudo rm -rif /Applications/DEVONthink\ Pro.app
```